# class extend SonataPagePage column not found

Tags: symfony4, sonata-admin, sonata

I just installed Sonata Page-Bundle, and want to create another page type.
Right now there is the default content types: site, page, block etc. I want to create an entity Article, which extends the SonataPagePage, containing the same fields but with extra fields that i can set in the article class.

I created this article entity, and persisted all its inherited properties to the database.

```
class Article extends SonataPagePage
```

This seemed to work, however, when i register the class in SonataAdmin i get an error saying the columns are not found:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT p0_.route_name AS route_name_0, p0_.page_alias AS page_alias_1, p0_.type AS type_2, p0_.position AS position_3, p0_.enabled AS enabled_4, p0_.decorate AS decorate_5, p0_.edited AS edited_6, p0_.name AS name_7, p0_.slug AS slug_8, p0_.url AS url_9, p0_.custom_url AS custom_url_10, p0_.request_method AS request_method_11, p0_.title AS title_12, p0_.meta_keyword AS meta_keyword_13, p0_.meta_description AS meta_description_14, p0_.javascript AS javascript_15, p0_.stylesheet AS stylesheet_16, p0_.raw_headers AS raw_headers_17, p0_.template AS template_18, p0_.created_at AS created_at_19, p0_.updated_at AS updated_at_20, p0_.id AS id_21, p0_.site_id AS site_id_22, p0_.parent_id AS parent_id_23, p0_.target_id AS target_id_24 FROM article a1_ ORDER BY a1_.id ASC':
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'p0_.route_name' in 'field list'").
```

I cannot seem to find any documentation about this. Either on sonata docs or stackoverflow.
How do i create this entity?

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ArticleRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ArticleRepository::class)
 */
class Article extends SonataPagePage
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the entire code for the Article entity ?

Comment: Column route_name not found mean there is probably no routeName property in your entity, does this property exists in SonataPagePage entity ? Also is your schema up to date ?